BotPress Knowledge Base Search Not Working for Flexible Queries
Why does the search in my Knowledge Base (KB) only work when the query exactly matches a specific format, like "Property Name: The Green Acres property detail," but not for more flexible queries like "Green Acres property"? How can I make the search function work for broader or less precise inputs?
